# Redirect visitors to another page if accessed directly using PHP

Tags: php

I have a `register.php` page, which allows visitors to register to become certain users. If they meet all requirements set by the form validation, they will be redirect to another page, called `thankyou.php` page.

My question is if anyone tries to visit the `thankyou.php` page **directly without going through/ from the `register.php` page, then it should redirect them back to the `register.php` page** again.

Note: I know how to use the `$_session = array();` for the logged-in users, and `header()` function very well. Once again, the question here requires some kind of research on how to restrict visitors from accessing `thankyou.php` directly (because visitors have not become users of the website yet).

Please don't guide me in jquery or javascript or any other languages. I need your help in php.

Thank you!

Comment: why don't you pass a parameter from register.php to thankyou.php which will validate the user. if this parameter is not set than a redirection happen

Comment: Set a flag in the session that allows the user to visit this page, remove the flag when they visited the page. Redirect anyone without that flag.

Comment: Have you tried to use `referer` header?

Comment: @YehiaAwad's advice is good. better if we unset it as per `Lyubomir Gavadinov's advice` below.

Answer (score 4):

In register.php you can set a key in the $_SESSION. For example

```
$_SESSION['justRegistered'] = true;
```

And the check for it in thankyou.php

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['justRegistered'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['justRegistered']);
    // Say Thank You
} else {
    header('Location: ... register.php');
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you unset the session variable?

Comment: If you don't unset it the user can visit thankyou.php multiple times without being redirected.

Comment: Yeah ok. But is that not allowed? Cause you already have registered and it is the same person.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first if the `$_SESSION` variable associated with the correct redirect to `thankyou.php` is setted.

After that, you have to check if the user `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` meets the requirements, that is if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (that contains the referral url) ends with `register.php` and the domain is your domain.

I suggest you to do something like (I'm assuming you defined a constant YOUR_HOST and used a session variable ok. Change it with yours as well):

```
if(empty($_SESSION['ok']) || empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    die(header('Location /register.php'));
}

$url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
if($url['host'] !== YOUR_HOST || $url['path'] !== 'register.php') {
    die(header('Location /register.php'));
}
// else show the thankyou page content
```

Comment: In my opinoin, I don't need the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` alone because it cannot be trusted, according to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php.

Answer (score 0):

you can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` in your thankyou.php .

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] != 'your referrer page'){
  header('location: yourtarget.php');
  die();
}
```

also using session is better way .

Comment: I tested and used session!

Answer (score 0):

One simple way for acheiving what you want is to send a session variable from `register.php` to `thankyou.php`. Sessions are a good way for permissions.

In `register.php` -> `$_SESSION['myvariable'] = 'something'`. then in `thankyou.php` you'll have access to the session variable and if the variable is set then you can stay in that page or do whatever you'll like. Keep in mind that you'll have to resume the session with `session_start()` in each page.

Comment: This is actually the clarification of the `Yehia Awad's` comment above. And I tested it successfully.